# Get named list of subgroup in golang regex

Tags: regex, go, regex-group

I'm looking for a function that returns a `map[string]interface{}` where `interface{}` can be a slice, a a `map[string]interface{}` or a value.

My use case is to parse WKT geometry like the following and retrieves point values; Example for a donut polygon:

`POLYGON ((0 0, 0 10, 10 10, 10 0, 0 0),(3 3, 3 7, 7 7, 7 3, 3 3))`

The regex (I voluntary set \d that matches only integers for readability purpose):

```
(POLYGON \(
    (?P<polygons>\(
        (?P<points>(?P<point>(\d \d), ){3,})
        (?P<last_point>\d \d )\),)*
    (?P<last_polygon>\(
        (?P<points>(?P<point>(\d \d), ){3,})
        (?P<last_point>\d \d)\))\)
)
```

I have a function (copied from SO) that retrieves some informations but it's not that good for nested groups and list of groups:

```
func getRegexMatchParams(reg *regexp.Regexp, url string) (paramsMap map[string]string) {
    match := reg.FindStringSubmatch(url)
    paramsMap = make(map[string]string)
    for i, name := range reg.SubexpNames() {
        if i > 0 && i <= len(match) {
            paramsMap[name] = match[i]
        }
    }
    return match
}
```

It seems that the group `point` gets only 1 point.
[example on playground](https://play.golang.org/p/OMAxKmp2tI)

[EDIT] The result I want is something like this:

```
map[string]interface{}{
    "polygons": map[string]interface{} {
        "points": []interface{}{
            {map[string]string{"point": "0 0"}},     
            {map[string]string{"point": "0 10"}},        
            {map[string]string{"point": "10 10"}},        
            {map[string]string{"point": "10 0"}},
        },
        "last_point": "0 0",
    },
    "last_polygon": map[string]interface{} {
        "points": []interface{}{
            {map[string]string{"point": "3 3"}},     
            {map[string]string{"point": "3 7"}},        
            {map[string]string{"point": "7 7"}},        
            {map[string]string{"point": "7 3"}},
        },
        "last_point": "3 3",
    }
}
```

So I can use it further for different purposes like querying databases and validate that last_point = points[0] for each polygon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to add some whitespace to the regex.

Also note that this engine won't retain all capture group values that are
within a quantified outer grouping like `(a|b|c)+` where this group will only contain the last a or b or c it finds.

And, your regex can be reduced to this

`(POLYGON\s*\((?P<polygons>\(\s*(?P<points>(?P<point>\s*(\d+\s+\d+)\s*,){3,})\s*(?P<last_point>\d+\s+\d+)\s*\)(?:\s*,\s*|\s*\)))+)`

https://play.golang.org/p/rLaaEa_7GX

---

The original:

`(POLYGON\s*\((?P<polygons>\(\s*(?P<points>(?P<point>\s*(\d+\s+\d+)\s*,){3,})\s*(?P<last_point>\d+\s+\d+)\s*\),)*(?P<last_polygon>\(\s*(?P<points>(?P<point>\s*(\d+\s+\d+)\s*,){3,})\s*(?P<last_point>\d+\s+\d+)\s*\))\s*\))`

https://play.golang.org/p/rZgJYPDMzl

See below for what the groups contain.

```
 (                             # (1 start)
      POLYGON \s* \(
      (?P<polygons>                 # (2 start)
           \( \s* 
           (?P<points>                   # (3 start)
                (?P<point>                    # (4 start)
                     \s* 
                     ( \d+ \s+ \d+ )               # (5)
                     \s* 
                     , 
                ){3,}                         # (4 end)
           )                             # (3 end)
           \s*            
           (?P<last_point> \d+ \s+ \d+ )  # (6)
           \s* \),
      )*                            # (2 end)
      (?P<last_polygon>             # (7 start)
           \( \s* 
           (?P<points>                   # (8 start)
                (?P<point>                    # (9 start)
                     \s* 
                     ( \d+ \s+ \d+ )               # (10)
                     \s* 
                     , 
                ){3,}                         # (9 end)
           )                             # (8 end)
           \s* 
           (?P<last_point> \d+ \s+ \d+ )  # (11)
           \s* \)
      )                             # (7 end)
      \s* \)
 )                             # (1 end)
```

Input

```
POLYGON ((0 0, 0 10, 10 10, 10 0, 0 0),(3 3, 3 7, 7 7, 7 3, 3 3))
```

Output

```
 **  Grp 0                -  ( pos 0 , len 65 ) 
POLYGON ((0 0, 0 10, 10 10, 10 0, 0 0),(3 3, 3 7, 7 7, 7 3, 3 3))  
 **  Grp 1                -  ( pos 0 , len 65 ) 
POLYGON ((0 0, 0 10, 10 10, 10 0, 0 0),(3 3, 3 7, 7 7, 7 3, 3 3))  
 **  Grp 2 [polygons]     -  ( pos 9 , len 30 ) 
(0 0, 0 10, 10 10, 10 0, 0 0),  
 **  Grp 3 [points]       -  ( pos 10 , len 23 ) 
0 0, 0 10, 10 10, 10 0,  
 **  Grp 4 [point]        -  ( pos 27 , len 6 ) 
 10 0,  
 **  Grp 5                -  ( pos 28 , len 4 ) 
10 0  
 **  Grp 6 [last_point]   -  ( pos 34 , len 3 ) 
0 0  
 **  Grp 7 [last_polygon] -  ( pos 39 , len 25 ) 
(3 3, 3 7, 7 7, 7 3, 3 3)  
 **  Grp 8 [points]       -  ( pos 40 , len 19 ) 
3 3, 3 7, 7 7, 7 3,  
 **  Grp 9 [point]        -  ( pos 54 , len 5 ) 
 7 3,  
 **  Grp 10                -  ( pos 55 , len 3 ) 
7 3  
 **  Grp 11 [last_point]   -  ( pos 60 , len 3 ) 
3 3
```

---

***Possible Solution***

It's not impossible. It just takes a few extra steps.
(As an aside, isn't there a library for WKT that can parse this for you ?)

Now, I don't know your language capabilities, so this is just a general approach.

**1. Validate the form you're parsing.**
This will validate and return *all polygon sets* as a single string in `All_Polygons` group.

Target `POLYGON ((0 0, 0 10, 10 10, 10 0, 0 0),(3 3, 3 7, 7 7, 7 3, 3 3))`

`POLYGON\s*\((?P<All_Polygons>(?:\(\s*\d+\s+\d+(?:\s*,\s*\d+\s+\d+){2,}\s*\))(?:\s*,\(\s*\d+\s+\d+(?:\s*,\s*\d+\s+\d+){2,}\s*\))*)\s*\)`

```
 **  Grp 1 [All_Polygons] -  ( pos 9 , len 55 ) 
(0 0, 0 10, 10 10, 10 0, 0 0),(3 3, 3 7, 7 7, 7 3, 3 3)
```

**2. If 1 was successful, set up a loop match using the output of `All_Polygons` string.**

Target `(0 0, 0 10, 10 10, 10 0, 0 0),(3 3, 3 7, 7 7, 7 3, 3 3)`

`(?:\(\s*(?P<Single_Poly_All_Pts>\d+\s+\d+(?:\s*,\s*\d+\s+\d+){2,})\s*\))`

This step is equivalent of a find all type of match. It should match successive values of all the points of a single polygon, returned in `Single_Poly_All_Pts` group string.

This will give you these 2 separate matches, which can be put into a temp array having 2 value strings:

```
 **  Grp 1 [Single_Poly_All_Pts] -  ( pos 1 , len 27 ) 
0 0, 0 10, 10 10, 10 0, 0 0  

 **  Grp 1 [Single_Poly_All_Pts] -  ( pos 31 , len 23 ) 
3 3, 3 7, 7 7, 7 3, 3 3
```

**3. If 2 was successful, set up a loop match using the temp array output of step 2.**
This will give you the *individual* points of each polygon.

`(?P<Single_Point>\d+\s+\d+)`

Again this is a loop match (or a find all type of match). For each array element
(Polygon), this will produce the individual points.

Target[element 1]  `0 0, 0 10, 10 10, 10 0, 0 0`

```
 **  Grp 1 [Single_Point] -  ( pos 0 , len 3 ) 
0 0  
 **  Grp 1 [Single_Point] -  ( pos 5 , len 4 ) 
0 10  
 **  Grp 1 [Single_Point] -  ( pos 11 , len 5 ) 
10 10  
 **  Grp 1 [Single_Point] -  ( pos 18 , len 4 ) 
10 0  
 **  Grp 1 [Single_Point] -  ( pos 24 , len 3 ) 
0 0
```

And,

Target[element 2]  `3 3, 3 7, 7 7, 7 3, 3 3`

```
 **  Grp 1 [Single_Point] -  ( pos 0 , len 3 ) 
3 3  
 **  Grp 1 [Single_Point] -  ( pos 5 , len 3 ) 
3 7  
 **  Grp 1 [Single_Point] -  ( pos 10 , len 3 ) 
7 7  
 **  Grp 1 [Single_Point] -  ( pos 15 , len 3 ) 
7 3  
 **  Grp 1 [Single_Point] -  ( pos 20 , len 3 ) 
3 3
```

Comment: Thank you for your simplification, but this is not what I asked. I edited my question to be more specific about the expected result

Comment: @GwydionFR - It may not be the answer you wanted to hear, but it is telling you why you never get more than  1 value in `point`. This `(?P<point>(\d \d), ){3,}` is a quantified capture group. This group will only contain the last `\d \d` it finds. Also, you have duplicate capture group names, likewise for that.

Comment: So it means it is impossible to get the result I want ? If it's a language limitation, then I'm fine with that and I can close this topic

Comment: @GwydionFR - I added a possible solution for you. Although, it's more a regex limitation than a _language_ one. This problem of not creating _group sets_ is common in most regex engines (Not Dot-Net, which does this in CaptureCollections).

Comment: I've done something similar, but still I am not very happy with this. Btw your answer will probably help a lot of folks out there. Thank you